# How to close all chrome browser tab using adb shell command?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-emulator, adb

I was trying to close all chrome browser tabs for an android device using ADB shell command using the following command which is not working.

```
am start -n com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity --action "org.chromium.chrome.browser.clear_tabs
```

any idea what could be the correct action ?

Comment: You command is defect. `am start` has no argument `--action`.

Comment: so what it should be ?

Comment: The [sourcecode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/12bfc336/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ChromeTabbedActivity.java#138) shows an action to close tabs, but that action is only available if a certain "command-line" option `enable-test-intents` has been set. I don't know how to do so.